# Jquery/Ajax duplicate append

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function which bring back the data from my ajax successfully but on clicking the add option row button and add sub option it seems to add another option/row, I need it to return just the data coming back from the ajax call 1 item to the current area. For some reason I don't think it's being reset? If I refresh the page the extra rows are not there.

Here is my JS:

```
function proOption(){

    $('#addProOption').click(function(e){
        $.getJSON('/ajax.html?type=option_type&id='+_id, function(_rowdata){
            if (_rowdata.ok == 1){
                $('#productOptions').append(_rowdata.o_form).show(500,function(){
                    proOption();
                    proSubOption();
                    proOptionDel(); 
                });
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}

function proSubOption(){

    var _optionLink = $('#form').find('.addRow');
    _optionLink.click(function(e){

        var _pid    = $(this).data("pid");
        var _optionSub  = $('#option_' + _pid + ' .optionSub');

        $.getJSON('/ajax.html?type=option&id='+_id+'&pid='+_pid, function(_data){
            if (_data.ok == 1){
                _optionSub.append(_data.o_form).show(500,function(){
                    proOption();
                    proSubOption();
                    proOptionDel(); 
                });
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}

function proOptionDel(){

    var _optionDelLink = $('#form').find('.deleteOption');

    _optionDelLink.click(function(e)
    {
        var _optionID   = $(this).data("id");
        var _optionSub  = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

        $.getJSON('/ajax.html?type=option_del&id='+_optionID, function(_rowdata){
            if (_rowdata.ok == 1){
                $(_optionSub).remove();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}

proOption();
proOptionDel();
proSubOption();
```

Here is my Html:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="productOptions">
        <div class="row-fluid" id="option_210">
            <div class="option">
                <div class="span11">
                    <label>Description:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="option_desc[]" maxlength="255" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="span1">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <a href="#" data-id="210" class="btn btn-small btn-red deleteOption"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                    <input type="hidden" name="option_id[]" value="210">
                    <input type="hidden" name="option_pid[]" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" name="option_price[]" value="0">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="optionSub">
                <div class="sub">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <label>Option:</label><input type="text" name="option_desc[]" maxlength="255" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span5">
                            <label>Price:</label><input type="text" name="option_price[]" maxlength="255" value="0.00">
                            <input type="hidden" name="option_id[]" value="211">
                            <input type="hidden" name="option_pid[]" value="210">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span1">
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <a class="btn btn-mini btn-default deleteOption" data-id="211" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <a data-pid="210" href="#" class="addRow btn btn-default">Add New Row</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="addProOption" data-pid="124" href="#" class="floatRight btn btn-default addOption">Add New Option</a>
</form>
```